# Set Highslide attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

This is working when using images:

```
$("#div).attr('onClick', 'return hs.expand(this)');
```

This is not when using ajaxed content:

```
$("#div").attr('onClick', 'return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'ajax'} )');
```

Probably there is something wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the word 'ajax' is really supposed to be embedded in the string then I guess you need double quotes:

```
$("#div").attr('onClick', 'return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: "ajax"} )');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of `.attr()`

```
$("#div").live('click', function () {
    return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'ajax'});
});
```